# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED to Apache2 server on same network

Tags: networking, apache-http-server

- So here is the scenario I've set up a phabricator server in house and
  I can connect to it from other computers on the network just fine
  using the internal IP address. "http://172.20.26.122/"
- I can also connect to it via the
  domain name from outside the network without any issues
  "phabricator.example.com"
- I can, on the machine itself, load up
  "phabricator.example.com" without any issues

  But I cannot go to "phabricator.example.com" from another computer on
  the same network without getting the error message
  "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

I am stumped on this problem and have looked all over for an answer. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question basically I had to alter the DNS settings on the LAN router to point to the specified internal IP address for the selected URL (FQDN).